# C# Mongodb how do I query a list with subset

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

```
    [
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61c474fd740cd6a46a7e8166"
    },
    "GroupIds": [
      {
        "$oid": "31c482ff6836e438631995ed"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "11c482ff6836e438631995ee"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "61bb96fb4c3d7106f5b9587a"
      }
    ],
    "Username": "Test"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61c474fd740cd6a46a7e8166"
    },
    "GroupIds": [
      {
        "$oid": "15c482ff6836e438631995ed"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "61c482ff6836e438631995ee"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "61bb96ee4c3d7106f5b95879"
      }
    ],
    "Username": "Test1"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "21c474fd740cd6a46a7e8166"
    },
    "GroupIds": [
      {
        "$oid": "61c482ff6836e438631995ed"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "61c482ff6836e438631995ee"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "61bb96ee4c3d7106f5b95879"
      }
    ],
    "Username": "Test2"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "31c474fd740cd6a46a7e8166"
    },
    "GroupIds": [
      {
        "$oid": "61c482ff6836e438631995ed"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "61c482ff6836e438631995ee"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "61bb96fb4c3d7106f5b9587a"
      }
    ],
    "Username": "Test3"
  }
]
```

Hello, I want to make multiple group based searches in mongo db,
I can make a single group based Search

```
 public async Task<List<List<ObjectId>>> UsersByGroupIdV3(List<List<string>> targetGroupses)
    {
        List<FilterDefinition<User>> query= new List<FilterDefinition<User>>();
        foreach (var targetGroups in targetGroupses)
        {
           
            if (targetGroups[0] != "allcountry")
            {

                query.Add(Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.GroupIds[0], new ObjectId(targetGroups[0])));

            }
            if (targetGroups[1] != "allCity")
            {
                query.Add(Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.GroupIds[1], new ObjectId(targetGroups[1])));
            }
            if (targetGroups[2] != "allDistrict")
            {
                query.Add(Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.GroupIds[2], new ObjectId(targetGroups[2])));
            }
        } 
        
        var match = Builders<User>.Filter.And(query);
         
        var users = await _userRepository.Find(match);

        var group = users.Result.Select(i => i.GroupIds);
        return group.ToList();
    }
```

There is a list of nested groups in the targetGroupses parameter
Example

```
[{["31c482ff6836e438631995ed","11c482ff6836e438631995ee","61bb96fb4c3d7106f5b9587a"]},{["15c482ff6836e438631995ed","61c482ff6836e438631995ee","61bb96ee4c3d7106f5b95879"]}]
```

var match = Builders.Filter.And(query);

If there is 1 list, it works fine, but if there is more than 1, how can I run the query?
I want to bring those in the America, Alaska, College or Germany Hessen Kreis groups

```
{[{"America", "Alaska", "College"}],[{"Germany", "Hessen", "Kreis"}]}
```

I want to fetch what's in this group from mongo db with c#